# How to fix "cannot read property 'style' of undefined" array outside of function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create an animation where several elements start in the center then move outwards to random positions. However, I keep getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'left' of undefined at magic.html:71`.

I can't figure out why it is undefined as it clearly is defined a few lines above?:
"`var fileArr = document.getElementsByClassName("rb");`"
I'm thinking that maybe it's because it's trying to access the array from within a function from within a for statement?

Here is my scripting (I 100% have 5 divs with the "rb" class and I 100% have called the function on body load and I am using jQuery.

```
function onLoad() {
    var wWidth = window.innerWidth - 260;
    var wHeight = window.innerHeight - 260;
    var fileArr = document.getElementsByClassName("rb");
    var finalPosW = [];
    var finalPosH = [];
    for(x = 0; x < fileArr.length; x++){
        finalPosW[x] = (Math.floor(Math.random() * wWidth) + 100) + "px";
        finalPosH[x] = (Math.floor(Math.random() * wHeight) + 100) + "px";
    }
    var fileArr = document.getElementsByClassName("rb");
    for(x = 0; x < fileArr.length; x++){
        var posW = 960;
        var posH = 540;
        setInterval(function(){
            if (posW == finalPosW && posH == finalPosH) {
                clearInterval();
            } else {
                posW++;
                posH++;
                fileArr.style.left = posW + 'px';
                fileArr.style.top = posH + 'px';
            }
        }, 5);
    }
}
```

I'm not entirely sure this will work even without this error but I am willing to cross that bridge when I come to it, I just need this array to work.

Comment: I think by doing a setInterval you are breaking the parent scope relationship.  That anonymous function will not get onLoad's variables. It will not see the fileArr variable.

Comment: Try add a `let` keyword in all `x` in your for loop: `for (let x = 0; ....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kindly change to

```
for(let x = 0; x < fileArr.length; x++){
        var posW = 960;
        var posH = 540;
        setInterval(function(x){
            if (posW == finalPosW && posH == finalPosH) {
                clearInterval();
            } else {
                posW++;
                posH++;
                fileArr[x].style.left = posW + 'px';
                fileArr[x].style.top = posH + 'px';
            }
        }.bind(this,x), 5);
    }
```

Comment: You should try explaining what you changed and why.